# Missing value for primary key id on

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a little problem.

I am getting this error

> Missing value for primary key id on AppBundle\Entity\User

This is my realtion with database 
[image]

And This is my entities

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="caller_machine")
 */
class CallerMachine {

/**
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $buttonNumber;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=false)
 */
private $linkToMusic;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $telephoneNumber;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $acceptRegulations;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(
 *      targetEntity = "AppBundle\Entity\CallerMachineVoice"
 * )
 * 
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(
 *      name = "number_id",
 *      referencedColumnName = "id",
 *      nullable = false
 * )
 */
private $numberMachine;
```

.......

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_name")
 */
class User {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length = 20, unique = true)
     */
    private $username;
```

...........

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="call_back_machine")
 */
class CallBackMachine {

    /**
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $buttonNumber;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $linkToMusic;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $telephoneNumber;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $acceptRegulations;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(
     *      targetEntity = "AppBundle\Entity\CallBackMachineVoice"
     * )
     * 
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(
     *      name = "number_id",
     *      referencedColumnName = "id",
     *      nullable = false
     * )
     */
    private $numberMachine;
```

.......

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="call_back_machine_voice")
 */
class CallBackMachineVoice {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(
     *      targetEntity = "AppBundle\Entity\User"
     * )
     * 
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(
     *      name = "users_id",
     *      referencedColumnName = "username",
     *      nullable = false
     * )
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $linkToMusic;
```

...............

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="caller_machine_voice")
 */
class CallerMachineVoice {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(
     *      targetEntity = "AppBundle\Entity\User"
     * )
     * 
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(
     *      name = "users_id",
     *      referencedColumnName = "username",
     *      nullable = false
     * )
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $linkToMusic;
```

When I create form

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('numbermachine', EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\CallerMachineVoice',
                    'choice_label' => 'user'
                ])
                ->add('buttonnumber', IntegerType::class, [
                    'label' => 'Podaj numer przycisku'
                ])
                ->add('linktomusic', TextType::class,[
                    'label' => 'Podaj link do muzyki'
                ])
                ->add('telephonenumber', IntegerType::class, [
                    'label' => 'Podaj numer przycisku'
                ])
                ->add('acceptregulations', IntegerType::class, [
                    'label' => 'Podaj numer przycisku'
                ])
                ->add('submit', \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'Zapisz'
                ));
    }
```

I have a problem, but When I remove line ,,numberMachine'' I see my form. Where is my problem ? Help me :)

ACTUALISATION

PRobably my problem is entity CallerMachineVoice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

On CallerMachineVoice:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne("User") 
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(
 *      name = "user_id",
 *      referencedColumnName = "id",
 *      nullable = false
 * )
 */
private $user;
```

Then define on User Entity __toString magic method:

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getUsername();
}
```

Comment: Thansk Strnm :)